# Domain shows wrong site in nginx, but only for HTTP

Tags: nginx, debian, web-server, virtualhost, http

I have multiple sites configured in Nginx `1.14.2-2+deb10u3` on Debian 10.

One is `a.mydomain.com`, another one is `b.mydomain.com`.

Both domains have two `server` blocks each, for port 80 and for port 443.

In all server blocks, the `server_name` is set.

All domains work as proxy servers to web applications inside of systemd nspawn containers.

Now both sites work well with HTTPS, but for HTTP all GETs to `a.mydomain.com` give results from `b.mydomain.com`. This also breaks automatic rewrite redirects from HTTP to HTTPS.

Any idea how to debug this? Can this happen, if the upstream web application of `a` is too slow or has an error? (Probably not, but I'm out of ideas at the moment.) Thank you!

Comment: Please show the output of `nginx -T`

Comment: This request was very helpful! Thanks!
It seems that include statements containing proxy_* directives inside of location blocks are somehow interpreted as if they are outside of any server block!
I just copied the lines literally (good-bye, DRY), and now the output of nginx -T looks much better.
The actual problem was, however, not related to Nginx at all, my question therefore invalid in the first place! One of the systemd nspawn containers grabbed port 80 because of a configuration error there!